# GRUB doesn't give the option to boot into Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, grub2

I  managed to download Ubuntu 11.10, burn an iso file on a cd and install it on a dell precision 380 along with windows xp. the problem is that ubuntu option does not appear when the computer is started. It seems my bootloader is not working properly. Any solutions?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

Here are two references you should look at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comments converted to answer Anonymous Oct 28 '11 at 11:14

Answer (score 0):

Shahid, when you select the Boot from CD at you Setup and you restart you computer, the first screen that will appear for you is with the "ISOLINUX..." text.

I think that you could verify this CD media in another machine and verify if your Setup is properly configured to boot up your CD driver.